# Есть куча ссылок вида http://example.com/file001.xhtml. Как все их сохранить в PDF?

Tags: html, http, google-chrome, macos, pdf

Есть очень много ссылок вида:

```
http://example.com/file001.xhtml
http://example.com/file002.xhtml
```

и так далее.

Как бы их отрендерить в браузере (например, в Chrome) и сохранить в PDF?
Руками через "Печать" — не вариант, поскольку ссылок довольно много.
Вроде бы задача весьма примитивная, но не могу понять, как лучше с нею разобраться?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тебе важно именно в pdf их перевести или получить с них данные для дальнейшей работы с ними?

Если второе то у Linux есть утила [wget](http://pingvinus.ru/note/wget-download-sites), которая умеет качать сайты. Если набросать скрипт и подсунуть ему список сайтов, то соответственно он тебе их скачает:

```
wget -r -k -l 7 -p -E -nc $1
```

и дать ему на вход файл со списком сайтов.

Если важно именно в pdf, то потом отправляешь на печать уже готовые файлы index.html

Comment: Ну скачать через wget понятно как. Мне именно в pdf надо конвертировать...

Comment: Ну и отправь index.html на печать в виртуальный принтер. Чем плох этот способ?

Comment: Т.е. соединить все в один файл и затем на виртуальном принтере напечатать? Хм, идея неплохая, спасибо, попробую.

Comment: можно напечатать каждый файл отдельно и потом соединить уже pdf-ки - может так будет лучше выглядеть

Comment: Там их больше ста, руками через меню распечатать каждый нереально. А как это сделать на автомате — не знаю. В этом как раз и вопрос...

Comment: нет я имел ввиду какой-нибудь консольный вирт. принтер и использование его по аналогии с wget: что-то вроде printPdf $1 $1.pdf

Comment: cups-pdf умеет это на Linux вроде